# Passing an IP Address string in C

Tags: c, ip, debian

I am trying to create a header file, within the header file I want to create a string to pass an IP address into my network file (/etc/network/interfaces)

Currently I have a header file set up and it includes the following:

```
char Board_IP[] = "192.168.40.3";
int n1, n2, n3, n4;
sscanf(ip, "%d.%d.%d.%d", &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4).
```

Then in my network file:

```
 address n1.n2.n3.n4
```

Whenever I try to restart my network, I always receive an error saying:

**Reconfiguring network interfaces...Error: an inet prefix is expected rather than "n1.n2.n3.n4/255.255.255.224"**

I know this is probably a simple question, but I am fairly new to this and would greatly appreciate some help.

Thank You!

Comment: `address n1.n2.n3.n4`....sounds confusing.

Comment: Well I figured that was the string for my IP.. n1 = 192, n2 = 168, n3 = 40 and n4 = 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [inet.pton](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_pton.3.html) function (the  "reversed" function is [inet.ntop](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_ntop.3.html) if needed afterwards).

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how this would work. I looked up the syntax for the two functions you specified, and it seems as though they are just for checking if they IP address is valid. Or am I completely wrong?

Comment: No it doesn't. You have a relatively simple example here: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=169505&seqNum=7
If you need more help don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but I guess I do not really understand the example.. I do not see where an IP is made into a string.